# Is $\mathbb{R}$ compact in the cofinite topology?

Tags: general-topology

[image: in]

This is what I did to show that its compact in the cofinite topology. Please let me know if this looks good and accurate. Give it a better style and notation if its needed. Appreciate your help!!

Comment: You might enjoy learning the [syntax for posting mathematical expressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  By "Give it a better style and notation" did you mean to invite others to get you started with that?

Comment: It could be written a bit better, but it’s correct and understandable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott great, thanks a lot for your response. This is what I needed to hear.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun: You’re welcome.

Comment: @hardmath Give it a better style and notation" did you mean to invite others to get you started with that? Answer: "It could be written a bit better, but it’s correct and understandable." This is what I expected. Glad that one of my frnds did that job. thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun Given that you've posted more than 100 questions and answers on this site, it might be worth while learning to use MathJax. It may be correct, but to me it is a lot more difficult to understand than MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Note that it can be extended to any set, not only $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Lemma.** Every set with the cofinite topology is compact.

*Proof.*
Indeed, consider an open covering $\mathcal{U}$ of a cofinite topological space $X$. Take any $U\in\mathcal{U}$, $U\neq\emptyset$. Since the topology is cofinite then $X\backslash U=\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$ is a finite set (possibly empty). Since $\mathcal{U}$ is a covering then for any $i$ there is $U_i\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $x_i\in U_i$. Therefore $\{U,U_1,\ldots, U_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. $\Box$

Comment: thanks a lot, I got it